# Terms Include elastic search numeric values

Tags: elasticsearch

The question I have is if there is a way to use a `terms include` on a `numeric field` in an `elasticsearch aggregation`.

I am using a generic query for multiple fields in elastic search and this is fine as most of my fields are `string values` and I can specify the unique field with an `include`. However one of my fields is a `numeric value` and is throwing this error:

```
"cannot support regular expression style include/exclude settings as 
they can only be applied to string fields"
```

So my question is, is there a an **equivalent to string matching include** for numeric values? I have tried using a `range set` from say 9 to 9 to match but it is not returning anything and unfortunately is keyed by the specified range and not the value of the `specified field` which is what I desire. Any input would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass numbers inside an `array` like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2) for exact match

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "numeric_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my_field",
        "include": [1,2,3]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!